# Regular Expression "Or" Return one group Java

Tags: java, regex

How do you return only a group that was found to match?

I have this regex:

```
".*>(\\d+.*)\\s.*\\(.*</|>(\\d+.+)<"
```

When I run:

```
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
   Matcher m = p.matcher(comparisonString);

   if(m.find() == true){
           System.out.println(m.group(1));
   }
```

Whenever the second part of the expression is matched (the expression after the 'OR' operator), null is returned. How do I return the matching group whenever the secondary expression (the expression after 'OR') is matched?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use capturing groups:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(regexToMatch1)|(regexToMatch2)");
...
read in stuff here
...
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(yourString);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    String firstString  = matcher.group(1);
    String secondString = matcher.group(2);
}
```

Then just throw away whatever groups you don't want.

good examples here:
http://javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/capturing_groups.shtml

Edit: Wait, I don't think I understand what you're asking. Your groups match, but the groups are null? You just need to reference the second group in your matcher.group(#); call.

Comment: Thanks! I ultimately ended doing this: 'if(m.group(1)!=null){
       System.out.println(m.group(1));
      }else{
       System.out.println(m.group(2));
      }'

Comment: Oh, so only one should match? In that case it would be easier to have two optional groups, one of which will match, using the ? operator: "(First group)?(Second group)?".